# What are different and better ways to make container width increase for large screen resolutions?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

What are different and better ways to make container width increase for large screen resolutions?

I have container width 1020px and 12 column responsive grid. I want this container width to increase for large screens and scale to different widths depending on screen resolution, from 1400px and above.

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS media queries! For example:

For resolution above 1400px:

```
@media (min-width: 1400px) { 
  .container{
    width: X px;
  }
}
```

For resolution in between 1020px and 1400px:

```
@media (min-width: 1021px) and (max-width: 1399px) { 
  .container{
    width: X px;
  }
}
```

For resolution below 1020px:

```
@media (max-width: 1020px) { 
  .container{
    width: X px;
  }
}
```

Read more about media queries here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Hope that helps!